# How to prevent implicit casting in functions?

Tags: c#

I am writing an Utility class which has methods like IsEquals and IsGreaterThanEquals that accept arguments of type double. When I send the float values to the methods they are implicitly converted to double and compared. I don't want this to happen. How to make sure float values are not implicitly converted to double and possibly throw compilation error when I send float type values instead of double type values?

```
public static bool Equals(double firstDouble, double secondDouble)
{
     return Math.Abs(firstDouble - secondDouble) <= double.Epsilon;
}
```

The above code works even if I pass float parameter values. I would like the compilation to throw error when I pass float parameter values to above method.

Comment: Similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762949/is-there-a-way-to-disable-implicit-casts-from-uint32-to-char

Comment: if you know you're sending float values, and you don't want to send float values, then why not just stop doing it? Have I missed the point? Also...what is the exact problem with sending floats? The whole point with implicit conversion is that it's essentially type safe - no data is lost, it's a widening conversion. So what issue are you actually trying to achieve via this requirement?

Comment: If you want to do something different with floats, then write a float specific version of your function.

Comment: Or write the good old `Equals(object, object)` , that puts you in charge of all typecasting.

Comment: @Neil, No this is not similar.

Comment: @Neil, No this is not similar.@ADyson, This is a Utility function, by mistake, some other developer might send floats. By the way, the epsilon is different for float and double. Hence double method cannot be used for float.

Comment: ok well if you're writing a library for others to use then explain that in the question, instead of saying things like "When I send"...it sounds like you're the only one who cares. It helps you know you want to control the use of it by others. Anyway, can you give a specific example of where the difference in Epsilon values would actually make a difference to the result? Also what's wrong with the built-in equality test for doubles, that you felt you need to write a new version?

Answer (score 10):

If you want an error during compilation, provide the methods with `float`'s, but mark them as [`Obsolete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute):

```
    [Obsolete("Don't use floats", error: true)]
    public static bool Equals(float a, float b) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Obsolete("Don't use floats", error: true)]
    public static bool Equals(double a, float b) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Obsolete("Don't use floats", error: true)]
    public static bool Equals(float a, double b) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static bool Equals(double firstDouble, double secondDouble) {
        return Math.Abs(firstDouble - secondDouble) <= double.Epsilon;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object as parameter type and check if they are of type double.

```
    public static bool Equals(object firstDouble, object secondDouble)
    {
        if(firstDouble is double && secondDouble is double)
            return Math.Abs((double)firstDouble - (double)secondDouble) <= double.Epsilon;
        throw new ArgumentException("parameter type should be double.");
    }
```

Comment: The OP wants a compile-time solution... Besides, this will require extra boxing and allocations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the expected size (int, long) so I just gave a sample of what is needed

```
       public static bool Equals(object firstDouble, object secondDouble)
        {
            if((firstDouble.GetType() != typeof(int)) || (secondDouble.GetType() != typeof(int)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
               return Math.Abs((int)firstDouble - (int)secondDouble) <= double.Epsilon;
            }

        }
```