# C# Is it possible to disallow constructors with implicit conversions?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, joda-money

I want to use the [Money](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) pattern to decrease the likelihood of mistakes that incur using raw numbers such as decimal, etc.

Some parts of the system use int64, representing money in minor units i.e. 12345¢. I want to make it explicit that money is **always** in major units i.e. $123.45, to prevent the disastrous consequences of accidentally using $12345.

The problem is that decimal is implicitly converted from a whole range of numbers including int64. Of course, I could easily create constructors for every number type and throw errors, but this only works runtime.

```
public Money(decimal amount, Currency currency)
{
    // OK
}

public Money(long amount, Currency currency)
{
    throw new Exception(...);
}
```

Ideally I want to prevent compilation. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You could cause compile-time checking by adding the [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-6.0) to the constructors that throw exceptions. Just set the `IsError` parameter to `true`: `[Obsolete("Pass a decimal, not a long.", true)]`.

Comment: See [Is there a way to disable implicit casts from UInt32 to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762949/is-there-a-way-to-disable-implicit-casts-from-uint32-to-char) and [How to prevent implicit casting in functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461515/how-to-prevent-implicit-casting-in-functions).